# Django admin tools new version model changes

Tags: python, django, django-admin-tools

I upgraded Django admin_tools to the latest version 0.5 . And I'm using Django 1.3

Now I am getting this error when I go to admin pages:

OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'admin_tools_dashboard_preferences.dashboard_id' in 'field list'")

There are no instructions mentioned in the documentation for fixing this. What ALTER TABLE should I fire without letting go of the old data?

PS: I do not use South.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you compare the tables formed before and after upgradation, then you can find the column which is missing and its definition. Just add it by using `Alter table`.

```
alter table admin_tools_dashboard_preferences add column `dashboard_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL;
```

Using this, the previous data will not only be retained, but the functionality will work too.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading django admin tools I faced the same problem and ended up dropping tables `admin_tools_dashboard_preferences` and `admin_tools_menu_bookmark` and recreating them using `python manage.py syncdb`. Obviously, it will erase all custom parameters you may set before so make sure you made a backup.